# Handling a model returned as json data from a controller in ASP.NET

Tags: json

I have a controller which return a model as json object:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[Route("GetById")]
public async Task <JsonResult> GetById([FromQuery]string id)
{
       var myfoo = new {foo="bar", baz="Blech"};
       return Json(myfoo);
}
```

How can handle the returned json object in jQuery?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $('#id').change(function () {
           var id = $('#id').val();
           if (id.length = 17) {
              $.ajax(
                 {
                    url: '/Home/GetById?id=' + id,
                    type: 'GET',
                    jsondata: "",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (jsondata) {
                        alert("foo is: " + jsondata ); <---?
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        //alert("error");
                    }
                }); 
        }
      });
</script>
```

I need to get foo value and assigned to an html control

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

all the time I was using capital letter

```
jsondata.foo // not .Foo
```